# Bash script to run through multiple log files and extract client IP from which URL was accessed

Tags: bash, scripting, ip, extract

I want to create a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script, that will run through multiple log files and print out client IP addresses, from which certain URL was accessed (for example https://test123.com). Every log file has content like:

```
"client_ip":"192.168.100.100"
```

I know that I need a loop, and I found way to extract any IP address using grep:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' $log1.txt
```

My question is how I can extract exactly this IP, which comes after "client_ip", and from which certain URL was accessed?

Also, string `"client_ip":"192.168.100.100"` is in the same line as requested URL. So, I need to extract line at the begin where my URL shows up and then extract from that line IP address, which comes after "client_ip". 
I am not so familiar with bash.

Could anyone help with that?

Comment: Is your input a JSON value? If so, consider using a JSON-oriented tool such as [tag:JQ]

Comment: You need to include sample input.  You talk about the URL being on the same line, but you never show an example of what that looks like.  Also, what do you want to do with duplicate IP's? Do you want to only show an IP once even if it shows up 10 times, do you want a separate count that shows how many times the IP shows up?

Comment: Yess, I have JSON value as input.

Comment: @PeraPetrovic then you'll want to ideally use `jq` as mentioned, but you still need to show a full snippit of JSON output

Comment: {"_json":{"vhost_proto":"https","vhost_port":"443","vhost_ip":"192.168.100.10","vhost":"www.test.com"

Comment: That's the sample input: "entry_path":"/URLIWANTTOFIND.pdf","client_ip":"192.168.50.30","backend_url":"http://x.x.x.x/URLIWANTTOFIND.pdf","audit_token":"<n/a>","action":"allowed"}}

Comment: @SiegeX At the begin, I want to know how I can extract and print out client_ip value for certain entry_path I define. After that, I can manipulate with values, show duplicates, count them, extract time etc.

Comment: please update the question with some sample data from your file ... lines that match your requirement, lines that don't match your requirement ... and then add a section to your question showing the desired output for said sample data

Comment: for beginners: you can pipe as many grep as you want, for example `grep -ih "urlwanttofind" ./*log*.txt | grep client_ip | grep -o <your-pattern-for-ip>` (advanced: use regex to match some pattern and output exact "column")

Comment: @PeraPetrovic Please edit your question with your sample input, not the comments.  Also, you need to give enough sample input that is representative of the JSON file.  For example, are these URL/client_ip's in an array? If so, we need to see that.